# SQL Select COUNT(Value=Value) Possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count

I want to Count all the rows that only have the value I want like this:

```
SELECT Users.Balance,
       Users.FreeBids,
       COUNT(Bids.Burned = 0) AS 'ActiveBids',
       COUNT(Bids.Burned = 1) AS 'BurnedBids'
FROM   Users
       INNER JOIN Bids
         ON Users.ID = Bids.BidderID
WHERE  Users.ID = 2
GROUP  BY Users.Balance,
          Users.FreeBids
```

It says "`Invalid Syntax Neat '='` It works perfectly without the '='.
How can I count the rows that Burned=1 in them and Burned=0 in them?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use a `CASE` statement

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN Bids.Burned=0 THEN 1 END) AS 'ActiveBids', 
COUNT(CASE WHEN Bids.Burned=1 THEN 1 END) AS 'BurnedBids'
```

There is an implicit `ELSE NULL`. `COUNT` only counts `NOT NULL` values so this will give you the result you need.

Comment: I prefer to use SUM in this case with an ELSE 0 in the case statement to eliminate the "Null value eliminated by aggregate" warning that this code causes.

Comment: @Danpe - `COUNT(NULLIF(Bids.Burned,1))` and `COUNT(NULLIF(Bids.Burned,0))` if the only valid values in that column are `0,1` and possibly `NULL`.

Comment: @Dave - Didn't think `COUNT` raised that but it apparently does. Yep that's another option if the warnings cause any problems.

Comment: @Martin Thanks the shorter version works :) and where do i see the warnings? And should they bother me?

Comment: @Danpe - They appear in the messages tab in SSMS if you have `ANSI_WARNINGS` on (which you almost certainly will). They are informational warnings not errors. They've never bothered me but I suppose the passing back of the message to your application may have some slight overhead.