# How to get percentages of maximum counts?

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have the following database table (`TableA`):

```
SlNo  TeamName  WorkInfo 
----  -------   -------  
1     Team1        0    
2     Team1        0    
3     Team1        1     
4     Team2        1    
5     Team2        1 
6     Team2        1      
7     Team3        0      
8     Team3        1
```

I also have two text boxes for selecting start and end dates and want to display details between the selected dates.

Currently the query below is giving the details based on the selected start date and end date.

```
SELECT
    TeamName,
    Count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN WorkInfo = 1 THEN SlNo END) AS Count1, 
    Count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN WorkInfo = 0 THEN SlNo END) AS Count0
FROM tableA 
WHERE (SubmitDate BETWEEN @start AND @end)
GROUP BY TeamName
```

It produces results like those given below:

```
TeamName   Count1   Count0
--------   -----    ------
Team1        1        2
Team2        3        0
Team3        1        1
```

But I instead want to display percentages based on the max counts in `Count1` and `Count0`.

For example, in the expected output below, 3 is the max `Count1` value; and based on that I have to translate count values to percentages of this max `Count1` value. Similarly, 2 is the max `Count0` value; and based on that I have to find the percentage of `Count0` values.

```
TeamName   Count1   Count0  Percentage1  Percentage0
--------   -----    ------  -----------  -----------
Team1        1        2        33.33%         100%
Team2        3        0        100%           0%
Team3        1        1        33.33%         50%
```

How can I modify my solution to produce the expected output?

Comment: Is this a database table? A DataTable of sorts? Is your ordering significant? What have you tried?

Comment: I used the given below query.
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableA. But it showing total table count only.

Comment: @vipintp yes because your counting the records in the table

Comment: Actually I am a fresher in this field. So that I posted my question here. But lots of people give down vote. can you give me some links with same answers!?

Comment: Not sure how this is "Too Broad" there is sample data and an expected output.

Comment: @Matt the "question" is _"I want display the team name and count in gridview on page load"_. It is unclear with what part specifically OP is having trouble (starting Visual Studio? Creating an ASP.NET Web App? Adding a new page? Adding a GridView?) and it is lacking what OP has tried.

Comment: @Matt "pretty obvious" isn't clear enough. We're not here to guess, but to answer specific, concrete, clear questions, which this wasn't at the time of closing.

Comment: @Matt you seem to want to defend your answer(ing). I find this a bad question and voted accordingly - and not worth answering. It's fine you guessed correctly what was meant (and trust me, I could've as well), but that doesn't make it a good question.

Comment: @CodeCaster Most questions from new users are that great, there not in tune with the site and don't know the correct etiquette etc, however jumping on every little mistake or missing information only drive people away from this site. No attempt in the comments were made to ask him to improve his question which could have been simply done by him stating more clearly it was a SQL question, thats it. In fact if he had included a few words, that it would have been it and it would be a regular 1 or 2 vote question no one would blink at.

Comment: @CodeCaster : Based on the value on "workInfo" column I want to display the count. If "Team1" contains 3 entries with work info values "0,0,1". Then I have to display the grid like TeamName CountOfOne CountOfZero

Comment: So your edit changed quite the meaning of your question. See [SQL Select COUNT(Value=Value) Possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773760/sql-select-countvalue-value-possible).

Comment: "select TeamName, count(distinct case when WorkInfo = 1 then SlNo end) as Count1   , count(distinct case when WorkInfo = 0 then SlNo end) as Count0 from tableA group by TeamName"
This query showing the exact out put.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TeamName, Count(TeamName) AS Count
FROM table
GROUP BY TeamName
```

You need to use the `Count` Function - To count the team name

And you need to use `group by` to determine how you want the counts to be grouped

Edited Answer.

```
SELECT TeamName, 
       Count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN WorkInfo = 1 
                           THEN SlNo end) AS Count1 , 
       Count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN WorkInfo = 0 
                           THEN SlNo end) AS Count0 
FROM tableA 
GROUP BY TeamName
```

Comment: "select TeamName, count(distinct case when WorkInfo = 1 then SlNo end) as Count1   , count(distinct case when WorkInfo = 0 then SlNo end) as Count0 from tableA group by TeamName"
This query showing the exact out put.

Comment: Ill add it to my answer for future clarification